# Intervaled argmax for a NumPy array with intervals defined by another array

Tags: arrays, numpy, unique, extract, weighted

I have a 1D array of sorted non-unique numbers. The number of times they repeat is random.
It is associated with an array of weights with the same size. For a given series of identical elements, the associated series of weights may or may not have repeated elements as well and in this whole array of weights, there may or may not be repeated elements. E.g:

```py
pos     = np.array([3, 3, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10])
weights = np.array([2, 10, 20, 8, 5, 7, 15, 7, 2])
```

I need to extract an array of unique elements of `pos`, but where the unique element is the one with the greatest weight.

The working solution I came up with involves looping:

```py
pos     = np.array([3, 3, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10])
weights = np.array([2, 10, 20, 8, 5, 7, 15, 7, 2])
# Get the number of occurences of the elements in pos but throw away the unique array, it's not the one I want.
_, ucounts = np.unique(pos, return_counts=True)
# Initialize the output array.
unique_pos_idx = np.zeros([ucounts.size], dtype=np.uint32)

last = 0
for i in range(ucounts.size):
    maxpos = np.argmax( weights[last:last+ucounts[i]] )
    unique_pos_idx[i] = last + maxpos
    last += ucounts[i]

# Result is:
# unique_pos_idx = [1 2 6 7]
```

but I’m not using much of the Python language or Numpy  (apart from the use of numpy arrays) so I wonder if there is a more Pythonesque and/or more efficient solution than even a Cython version of the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach -

```
sidx = np.lexsort([weights,pos])
out = sidx[np.r_[np.flatnonzero(pos[1:] != pos[:-1]), -1]]
```

Possible improvement(s) on performance -

1] A faster way to get the sorted indices `sidx` with `scaling` -

```
sidx = (pos*(weights.max()+1) + weights).argsort()
```

2] The indexing at the end could be made faster with `boolean-indexing`, specially when dealing with many such intervals/groupings -

```
out = sidx[np.concatenate((pos[1:] != pos[:-1], [True]))]
```

**Runtime test**

All approaches :

```
def org_app(pos, weights):
    _, ucounts = np.unique(pos, return_counts=True)
    unique_pos_idx = np.zeros([ucounts.size], dtype=np.uint32)    
    last = 0
    for i in range(ucounts.size):
        maxpos = np.argmax( weights[last:last+ucounts[i]] )
        unique_pos_idx[i] = last + maxpos
        last += ucounts[i]
    return unique_pos_idx

def vec_app(pos, weights):
    sidx = np.lexsort([weights,pos])
    return sidx[np.r_[np.flatnonzero(pos[1:] != pos[:-1]), -1]]

def vec_app_v2(pos, weights):
    sidx = (pos*(weights.max()+1) + weights).argsort()
    return sidx[np.concatenate((pos[1:] != pos[:-1], [True]))]
```

Timings and verification -

For the setup, let's use the sample and tile it `10000` times with scaling, as we intend to create `1000` times more number of intervals. Also, let's use unique numbers in `weights`, so that the `argmax` indices aren't confused by identical numbers :

```
In [155]: # Setup input
     ...: pos = np.array([3, 3, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10,])
     ...: pos = (pos + 10*np.arange(10000)[:,None]).ravel()
     ...: weights = np.random.choice(10*len(pos), size=len(pos), replace=0)
     ...: 
     ...: print np.allclose(org_app(pos, weights), vec_app(pos, weights))
     ...: print np.allclose(org_app(pos, weights), vec_app_v2(pos, weights))
     ...: 
True
True

In [156]: %timeit org_app(pos, weights)
     ...: %timeit vec_app(pos, weights)
     ...: %timeit vec_app_v2(pos, weights)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 56.4 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.77 ms per loop

In [157]: 56.4/1.77 # Speedup with vectorized one over loopy
Out[157]: 31.864406779661017
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Divakar. I'm learning a lot of tricks in your reply. 
In your code above, should I consider that `np.flatnonzero(pos[1:] != pos[:-1])` is somewhat an alternate way of locating unique elements in an array? From my perspective It's as if we're rejecting where we have zero derivative and keep the rest.  Do I understand correctly that you append the -1 to it by considering that this way of sorting make it so that the last element is necessarily the one with the biggest weight?

Comment: @user31412 That `np.flatnonzero(pos[1:] != pos[:-1])` is basically getting the indices where the intervals *change* with slicing of one-shifted slices. We need those because we intend to get the last of each group which because of lexsort/argsort would represent the maximum arg of each group/interval. That last -1 is needed because the slicing would have missed out on getting the last element of the last group. So, we add that manually. This gives us the argmax for the last group, because sidx would have gotten that one as the last element. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Sure, it makes sense to me. I'm going to play with the different approaches you offered. Thanks a lot. I'll mark this answer accepted as soon as i'm sure I understood everything you wrote.

Comment: In the real case, there can be identical weights. What would happen then? To me it doesn't matter what `pos` index is chosen in case the weights associated with identical `pos` elements are identical, but will this be ok too for the algorithm? Like slow down or anything like that?

Comment: For example, with the same `pos` but changing the weights to
`weights = np.array([2, 10, 20, 20, 8, 5, 5, 15, 7, 2])`

Comment: @Wall-E Are you asking if having identical weights would slow down the alogorithm? Answer is No. For identical weights, if you want to choose the first of those, use argsort with its optional arg `kind` as `mergesort`.

Comment: The documentation doesn't show the use of other sorting "keys" with np.argsort, which to me was the point of using np.lexsort in your reply. Could I also use `np.argsort()` in the same manner as `np.lexsort()` and just adding "kind"?
E.g: `sidx = np.argsort([weights,pos], kind='mergesort')`
Although it doesn't matter which element index is chosen, the point is to have a deterministic results across tests and different machines.

Comment: @Wall-E That scaling : `pos*(weights.max()+1) + weights` acts as using `pos` as the keys. The way you need to use `kind` is : `(pos*(weights.max()+1) + weights).argsort(kind='mergesort')`. This would give you the deterministic results  that you are after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156604/discussion-between-wall-e-and-divakar).